# how to use Picasso library to cut the image from bottom only

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using the below code to load the image into an imageView.I want to cut the image from the bottom only. how can I do this using Picasso Tried center-crop and image cut from top and bottom

```
  Picasso.with(getContext())
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .fit()
                    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: You need to create a custom transformation for that . For reference you can have look at [This](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using transform you can crop the image based on the gravity.

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .transform(new CropTransformation(500,150),  CropTransformation.GravityHorizontal.CENTER, CropTransformation.GravityVertical.TOP))
       .into(imageView);
```

The above code will cut the image from the bottom only.

You can get CropTransformation library [here](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations).

Comment: @Sam `CropTransformation` is a part of the link i have attached above .

Comment: I have attached the transformation library to my answer. @Sam, You can also get it from ADM's comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this .centerCrop(Gravity.TOP)

```
   Picasso.get()
                .load(GlobalApplication.BaseUrl +"/" + item.AD_THUMBNAIL)
                .resize(180, 145)
                .centerCrop(Gravity.TOP)
                .into(holder.imgAd);
```